# Regex to match string between quotes

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I'm using a shell script to read in a file and then piping the output to grep and trying to extract the string contained between two quotes (while excluding the quotes).

```
./readFile.sh | grep -e "[\^\"]*[\?\"]"
```

This returns the entire contents of the file I that I'm reading.

My file is organized this way:

```
TITLE="foo"
DATA="bar"
SERVER="foo.bar.server"
```

I read the regex tutorial here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html and tried to use the lookahead and lookbehind as best as I could, but I don't understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check this example with `grep`  with look-behind

```
kent$  echo 'TITLE="foo"
DATA="bar"
SERVER="foo.bar.server"'|grep -Po '(?<=")[^"]*'
foo
bar
foo.bar.server
```

alternative is `grep -Po '"\K[^"]*'`

Comment: this works, however, I get two blank lines between the output of each string

Comment: what is the output of your `readFile.sh`? if it looks exactly same as the example in the answer, there is no empty lines.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give awk a chance it is pretty simple:

```
awk -F '"' 'NF>2{print $2}' inFile
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you use a script for file reading, since grep works with files, but it's your own choice (maybe you do some preprocessing).

This extracts what is between '"':

```
$ grep -o '".*"' <file>
"foo"
"bar"
"foo.bar.server"
```

If you need to get rid of '"':

```
$ grep -o '".*"' <file> | tr -d '"'
foo
bar
foo.bar.server
```

Comment: well my script doesn't just read files, I just made it seem that way for the simplicity of my example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `grep` to return only the matching strings (and not the entire line) you should use the `-o` (or `--only-matching`) option.